# UPS World Ship software cannot connect to ODBC stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, networking, stored-procedures, odbc, ups

I'm trying to setup UPS World Ship software to use a keyed import. I'm connecting my import to a stored procedure from our database, but that stored procedure is not showing up. in fact, none of our procedures are listed. We've use other shipping software in the past with these same procedures without issue.

I'm expecting to see a list of stored procedures that we have deployed at Database > Programmability > Stored Procedures:

[image]

Nearest I can tell, we are only seeing these tables:

[image]

Screenshot from World Ship. This drop down should show all tables/procedures:
[image]

Does anyone know if there is a specific ODBC driver, or setting that I might be missing? Or something on the stored procedure itself? Or, is the World Ship software simply incapable of calling a stored procedure?

Comment: *"in fact, none of our procedures are listed."* Then they aren't on that database or, based on the image, you haven't refreshed the object explorer after creating them.

Comment: They are on that db. Should note we've used other shipping software that did show the procedures.

Comment: Given the title above the list is "ODBC Tables", that implies your source must actually be a table. And given this [documentation](https://www.ups.com/worldshiphelp/WSA/ENU/AppHelp/mergedProjects/IMPEXP/PROCEDURES/Import_Information_into_WorldShip.htm) it seems that software only works with tables.

Comment: I was thinking that was likely the issue, but didn't see any documentation stating it outright, but even so, it's not even showing our tables, just only tables like sys.all_columns.

Comment: But your images show multiple tables that are obviously not provided by sql server (i.e., "our tables"). Perhaps you also have a permissions issue? No one but you knows how you configured this to work and guessing is not the best debugging approach.